# How do I stop moving focus on Enter keypress in Nativescript (Android)?

Tags: android, nativescript, nativescript-vue

Playground example: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=FZ3GR1&v=4

I'm using Nativescript-Vue on an Android device, if you type a value into the first textfield and then press enter, focus is moved to the second textfield.

How do I stop this? I do not want the focus to change at all as I will be handling the Enter keypress. I can move the focus back but I would rather it didn't move at all.

I feel I'm missing something very obvious!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nativescript's `TextField` has a property called `returnKeyType` that sets the soft keyboard's return type. You can set it to `done` if you want to just close the keyboard.

```html
<TextField returnKeyType="done"></TextField>
```

More information about that in the [docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/keyboard#return-key-type)

Comment: Thanks! I had tried this on the device to no avail, the text input is actually a barcode scanner, so you've made me realise the issue lies there and not with the textfields themselves.

Comment: Just a note, this doesn't seem to work on the `<TextView>` element. Instead of closing the keyboard it just moves down a line.